# VAIO Laptop not booting Windows - Boots Splashtop OS instead

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop, sony-vaio

I am having problems with my VAIO Laptop. It is a E Series Windows 7 Home Premium 64BIT machine.

The problem is that it keeps on booting up the Quick Web Access evenn when I press the power button. I tried shutting down completely, re-installing the windows, re-installing the drivers and also did a format to my hard disk. I can access Windows if I start it with the ASSIST button and then by immediately pressing F10 repeatedly and then choosing to start Windows normally. But it is not booting up from the power button. The power button and the WEB button seem to be doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I have not try to reinstall my windows, but to get back to Windows normally is to long press the power button until the laptop shuts down, and then press the power button again to power on, and quickly do Ctrl+Alt+del combination.